# Java Mysql Order by Price

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using Google cloud mysql v.5.5 for a Java based development.

I am trying to order by the resulting data set by price, but until now, prices arent being ordered.

Lets say my query is :

```
SELECT ID, ITEM_NAME, PRICE FROM REFERENCES .... ORDER BY PRICE ASC
```

Table References has 4 elements. The prices for those elements are : 1, 12, 12.2 and 2.

When i run the query what i am getting is :

```
1
12
12.2
2
```

And i should be getting :

```
1
2
12
12.2
```

Any idea what might going on?

Thank you in advance for your time,

Kind regards,

UPDATE1: The field type for PRICE column is VARCHAR as a client prereq, so not much to do about this.

UPDATE2: Price value contains a ',' instead of the usual '.' , so even with the responses i've got until now the results keep being less messy but messy anyways. :(

UPDATE3: Also, i have tried to do the following : ORDER BY replace(PRICE, ',', '')+0 ASC but this also has proven to be unsuccessful. :(

Comment: You should store prices as `DECIMAL`, not `VARCHAR` or whatever you have. Otherwise, this is the tiniest problem you can face.

Comment: Storing them as VARCHAR its more a client requirement than my own idea.  And now i am facing this problem. :(

Comment: Beware of such requirement: sooner or later you'll find a row with `Ask Jim` as value. Go figure when you need to apply taxes or calculate cart totals... But I guess it could be worse: the client could have wanted to use scanned pictures of the product labels.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like `price` is being stored as a string and not a number.

You can try:

```
order by price + 0
```

This will convert it to a number.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT ID, ITEM_NAME, PRICE FROM REFERENCES .... 
ORDER BY cast(PRICE as unsigned) ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

I bet the price column is not numeric but alphanumeric. In that case, the sort order is alphanumeric, so you get

> 1
>   12
>   12.2
>   2

because `1 < 2` and `12 < 12.2`.

Answer (score 0):

- First thing to know that..**Google Cloud SQL** supports and uses all the features of **MySQL 5.5**.
- MYSQL sorts query results in ascending **ORDER BY** default.
- You have to make your **PRICE** column **FLOAT**.

**SELECT ID, ITEM_NAME, PRICE FROM REFERENCES .... ORDER BY PRICE ASC**

Or Simply

**SELECT ID, ITEM_NAME, PRICE FROM REFERENCES .... ORDER BY PRICE**

And Output-
  **1**  **2**  **12**  **12.2**